# Page validation: Inline Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to get a form to validate within http://validator.w3.org/, I have a form that has options created by Javascript this is done to simplify date selection by users.

The inline javascript creates:

- The current year and month (arrival date)
- A future year and month (departure date)

I have thought of converting the javascript to PHP but is there any way to maintain the javascript but at the same time being able to pass the validation test?

the javascript code is:

```
<div class="dateBE">Fecha de llegada</div>
<select class="fieldTRA" id="b_checkin_day" name="checkin_monthday" onchange="checkDateOrder('frm', 'b_checkin_day', 'b_checkin_month', 'b_checkout_day', 'b_checkout_month') ; tickCheckBox('b_availcheck');">
<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option>

 </select>

 <select class="fieldTRA" id="b_checkin_month" name="checkin_year_month" onchange="checkDateOrder('frm', 'b_checkin_day', 'b_checkin_month', 'b_checkout_day', 'b_checkout_month') ; tickCheckBox('b_availcheck');">

**<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
            var monthArray=new Array("enero","febrero","marzo","abril","mayo","junio","julio","agosto","septiembre","octubre","noviembre","diciembre");
var today = new Date();
      var month= today.getMonth();
      var year = today.getFullYear()%100;
      var fullYear=today.getFullYear();
      year=new String(year);
      year=addzero(year);
      var countMonth=month;
      for(var i=0;i<12;i++,countMonth++){
    if(countMonth%12==0 && i>0){
   countMonth=0;
   year++;
   year=new String(year);
   year=addzero(year);
   fullYear++;
    }
    document.writeln("<option value=\""+fullYear+"-"+(countMonth+1)+"\">"+monthArray[countMonth]+" '"+year);
    }
/* ]]> */
</script>
  </select>
</div>**


<div id="homeout">
<div class="dateBE">Fecha de salida</div>


<select class="fieldTRA" id="b_checkout_day" name="checkout_monthday" onchange="tickCheckBox('b_availcheck');">
<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option>

 </select>
 <select class="fieldTRA" id="b_checkout_month" name="checkout_year_month" onchange="tickCheckBox('b_availcheck');">
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
      var monthArray=new Array("enero","febrero","marzo","abril","mayo","junio","julio","agosto","septiembre","octubre","noviembre","diciembre");
      var today = new Date();
      var month= today.getMonth();
      var year = today.getFullYear()%100;
      var fullYear=today.getFullYear();
      year=new String(year);
      year=addzero(year);
      var countMonth=month;
      for(var i=0;i<12;i++,countMonth++){
if(countMonth%12==0 && i>0){
   countMonth=0;
   year++;
   year=new String(year);
   year=addzero(year);
   fullYear++;
}
document.writeln("<option value=\""+fullYear+"-"+(countMonth+1)+"\">"+monthArray[countMonth]+" '"+year);
}

/* ]]> */
</script>
  </select>
</div>

            </div>
```

The form can be seen here: http://www.visitar.com

Comment: Yes, you should convert it to PHP - there's nothing that needs to happen clientside

Comment: I agree with @Bergi that this should be created with PHP, however, if you want to use javascript, don't use `document.writeline`, it is just bad form.  Instead you could reference the `select` tag and insert your own `option` nodes into it, via native javascript or a library like jQuery.  This way you wont need to have the script tag within the select.

Comment: Thanks Bergi, unfortunately I do not have a strong enough grasp of PHP to be able to do it (taking into account leap years etc). I asked for help and here and got downvoted lol! Is there a good resource you could suggest for me to be able to convert it?

Comment: What is your problem fixing the [validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.visitar.com)?

Comment: Exactly I just need to have the page validate.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to move all form/html construction logic to PHP. What you do here is some quite obscure mix because you add values to the form in javascript and process these values in PHP code on the server.

If you're looking for a way to do this with javascript take a look at jQuery that helps you a lot writing unobtrusive JS code. Example:

```
$(function() {
    var opt = "";

    // Date calculations left out
    for(var i=0;i<12;i++,countMonth++) {
        opt += "<option value=\""+fullYear+"-"+(countMonth+1)+"\">"+monthArray[countMonth]+" '"+year; 
    });

    $('#b_checkout_month').append(opt);   
}
```

This script can be included in the head or just before closing the body tag because it does not rely on direct document access but references the select option by the jQuery selector $('#b_checkout_month').

Comment: Yes it a tricky one because you would need to submit the form to get the departure date... that makes putting all the form into php not suitable. There needs to be a mix here I am working on it!